# @Html.EnumDropDownListFor - Dropdown values not being set

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a basic form allowing users to input details which then gets posted and saved to a database - this works as expected without any issues:

```
@model R32.Register.Models.RegisterCar
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Your R32";
}

<h2>Edit R32</h2>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateCar", "Garage", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter details</legend>
            <ol>                   
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumberPlate)
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NumberPlate, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NumberPlate)
                </li>                    
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Edition)
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Edition, "Select an edition:", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Edition)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Colour)
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Colour, "Select a colour:", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Colour)
                </li>                    
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

Model snippet:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name="Edition")]
public MkEnum? Edition { get; set; }
```

Enum:

```
public enum MkEnum
{
    [Display(Name="Mk4")]
    Mk4 = 1,
    [Display(Name="Mk5")]
    Mk5 = 2
}
```

The control renders as expected, with the Edition dropdownlist having three values: "Select an edition", "Mk4", and "Mk5".

The user is able to select an edition, control is validated, then posted to the controller.

The Post is successful, and all selected values are sent to the controller - the app then persists the data in a database, and so on, without any problems.

The issue is when I pass this model back into the same View to allow the user to edit the saved data, the saved values for the enums are NOT being set as the selected value in the dropdownlist.

I can confirm that any saved string values, such as NumberPlate in this example, are being passed back into the view and loaded into the UI.

Putting a breakpoint on the viewmodel as it renders I can confirm that my @model contains the saved values for enum properties - Edition for example - but the end result is that the "Select an edition:" dropdown list is rendered containing the expected dropdown values, but it's value is the default "Select an edition:" instead of the actual value passed in via. m.Edition.

I have been able to get this working using DropDownListFor - but am having difficulties in understanding why this is not working using EnumDropDownListFor, as this clearly seems like a more elegant solution.

Does anyone have any help/advice for this?

Comment: This is not possible with an EnumDropDownList as far as I know. You can write a generic extension method to convert enums in to SelectLists. [This](http://geeksharp.com/2011/11/02/power-up-your-enumerations/) sample code may help.

Comment: It should work. Did you try putting the code in a sample MVC application and check what is happening?

Comment: If the value of `Edition` is `MkEnum.Mk5` when you pass the model to the view, then the 3rd option will be selected when the view is rendered. If its not, there is something else wrong in your code. Show the controller methods. (and as a test, just add `@DisplayFor(m => m.Edition)` in your view to see what the output is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so from what I could see the problem was caused by using an ActionLink to pass back the full model of an item being edited. Everything was being sent back in a Query string, so my Enum values were being passed to the controller in the following way: mkEnum=Mk4.

I was then loading the UpdateCar view as seen above in my example - but the query string values were being persisted in the call back to the View.

EnumDropDownListFor is unable to interpret/convert the text value of enums into their actual values - if I manually edited the Query string to mkEnum=1, then the correct value wasloaded into the ViewModel.

In addition to this problem, it was not a good solution passing the full model back to the controller. 
I've modified the code to pass back a single Id of the item being edited - the controller then verifies the user has access to that Id, retrieves the Model from the Database then passes it back to the same View as in my above example.

With this change my dropdowns are now being updated with their values without any issues.

TLDR; If you experience this issue check to make sure you don't have model properties, specifically enum values represented by their string values, in a query string when loading your view and using EnumDropDownListFor.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself. This happens because fields of type enum are being passed back to the browser serialized as their enum names, but @Html.EnumDropDownListFor generates its option values as integers. The browser can't match up the two so the dropdown stays at its default selection.

There are 3 ways to get around this.

1. Get the view model's enum field to serialize properly as an int.
2. Write a dropdown generator that uses enum names as option values.
3. Use javascript to manually select the option (includes razor syntax here)

   ```
   $("#YourDropdownID option").each(function () {
       if ($(this).html() == '@(Html.DisplayFor(o => o.YourEnumFieldName))') {
           $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
           return;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: This was related to fix I found - in my case the solution was identifying that I didn't need to be passing back the Enum string values to my View as part of the query string.